# Converting float raster to integer failing in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, raster-conversion, integer, error-010429

I'm trying to convert a 32 bit floating raster into an integer type using the 'int' spatial analyst tool within ArcGIS Pro (2.8.3).

I have used the raster calculator to remove the decimals (in my case, multiplying by 100,000 as there are 5 decimal places - e.g. 7.10105 converted to 710,105). However, when I then attempt the int run I get the following error:

> "ERROR 010429: Error in GRID IO: MtVatBldNew: Value range for
> d:\gis\derry_~1\rasters\derryukcint2  exceeds 100000."

I am using an external hard drive with 350GB of space available, and cannot see anything to suggest that the raster is corrupted.

Comment: It's possible that you hit limit for integer number computer can handle. More importantly why are you doing this? It generates ginormous number of unique values,  what are you going to do with them?

Comment: The raster information is showing depth contours in a flood scenario - I wanted to convert to a polygon so I can do some additional risk analysis including how many properties are situated within a specific depth band. I realise I probably could have done this an easier way, though I have now managed to get the integer step to work by writing it as a .tif!

Comment: I use reclassify to do the same thing.